# Rails Application : Getting Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'ckeditor-jquery'
(in /home/jeeva/Projects/Codebases/acu-arogya/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)
```

**

**I am Using CKeditor in my rails application but i'm getting error in javascript 
My application.js file contains:**
//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs

//= require turbolinks

//= require ckeditor-jquery

//= require twitter/bootstrap

//= require_tree .

Comment: Well, it looks like that the ckeditor-jquery file is not to be found. Did you use ckeditor gem or are you using bower?

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea to try:

Swap the position of

```
//=require_tree .
```

with the position of

```
//= require ckeditor-jquery
```